# Jquery autocomplete box staying in same place when scrolling the page

Tags: jquery, css, autocomplete, scroll, jquery-autocomplete

When I use the jquery autocomplete, and when the box appears, then when I scroll down the page, the box stays in the same position. How can I just keep the menu right under the textfield when the user scrolls?

Also in my code, I have an onkeyup event that runs an ajax function and when it returns, I change the contents of the autocomplete tags using this

```
        // get the search box element
        var input = $("#" + searchBoxID);

        // set its autocomplete tag list
        input.autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });

        // force its autocomplete menu to show
        input.autocomplete("search", input.val());
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Also I found some answer about using the `appendto` code
[jQuery-autocomplete scroll issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558290/jquery-autocomplete-scroll-issue).

But I'm not sure how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use position attribute of CSS style to make the autocomp box relative to input box.

position: "relative";